# Finishing a child Activity, in a different process, from parent Activity. finishActivity() not working

Tags: java, android

I have an `Activity` [Activity1] that starts a `Runnable` called [ProRunnable] and in the `run()` of `ProRunnable` i have an instance of a class called [TExecutor] that i call a method on.

That method then starts another `Activity` [Activity2] for result. The `Activity2` starts a `Callable` with `ExecutorService`.

`TExecutor` contains a reference to `Activity1`. **How can i force `Activity2` to finish from outside `Activity2`? I need `Activity2` to finish and the `Callable` to stop running too.**

I have tried `activity1.finishActivity(1)` where "1" is the request code i used to start `Activity2` in `TExecutor`. But it never calls the `onDestroy` of `Activity2`. And i do not see that it is trying to finish the `Activity2`.

After i make the call for the activity to finish, it does not appear to go into `onDestroy` and the callable continues to run.

`Activity2` has no theme, so it basically runs in the background. It is also in a different process. I set all this in the manifest, shown at bottom.

Sounds confusing, i know. If you need more information, let me know.

Thanks

---

```
public class Activity1 extends FragmentActivity {

    private ProRunnable proRunnable;
    private Thread thread;

    public onStart() {

        this.proRunnable = new ProRunnable(this);
        this.thread = new Thread(this.proRunnable);
        this.thread.start();
    }

    ON BUTTON PRESS {

        this.finishActivity(Activity2.REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {

        if(reqCode == Activity2.REQUEST_CODE) {

            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ProRunnable implements Runnable {

    private TExecutor tExecutor;
    private Activity activty1;

    public ProRunnable(Activity activity) {

        this.activity1 = activity;
    }

    public void run() {

        this.tExecutor = new TExecutor(this.activity1);
        this.tExecutor.execute();
    }
}
```

---

```
public final class TExecutor {

    private final Activity activity1;
    private Intent activity2Intent;

    public TExecutor(Activity activity) {

        this.activity1 = activity;
    }

    public void execute() {

        this.activity2Intent = new Intent(activity1.getBaseContext(), Activity2.class);
        this.activity2Intent.startActivityForResult(this.activity2Intent, Activity2.REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private ExecutorService executor;

    protected void onStart() {

        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        InsertThread insert = new InserterThread();
        this.executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<Boolean> submit = this.executor.submit(inserter);

        try {

            submit.get();
        } catch ... {
        }
    }

    private class InserterThread implements Callable<Boolean> {

        public InserterThread() {

        }

        public Boolean call() throws ... {

            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                for(...) {

                    if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void onDestroy() {

            super.onDestroy();
            Log.e(TAG, "DESTROYING THE ACTIVITY");
            this.executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<manifest...>
    <application android:process="package.path.p1">
        <activity android:name="package.path.Activity1"/>
        <activity android:name="package.path.Activity2" android:process="package.path.p2" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually moved them into separate apps completely. And changed the structure quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try the other functions in the shutdown [Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png) of `Activity2` after `TExecutor` calls `activity1.finishActivity(1)`. I suspect that `Activity2` is actually receiving `onPause()` or `onStop()`, just not `onDestroy()`, which is only invoked by system whim based on resources availability.

Comment: I will try this as soon as i get the chance. Thanks

Comment: I am not seeing either of those methods called when i try to finish `Activity2`.

Comment: Without actually implementing your Activities in my development environment and experimenting I cannot help you any further, and I just don't have the time to do that right now :(

Comment: WHAT!? You dont have the time to dedicate to my every need? You are a terrible person and you should feel ashamed. =) I think we have figured out a different solution that will be better anyways. If it works out, i will post it here. Thanks

Comment: No worries. I hope the work-around solved the problem for you.